# Raycaster fails to detect Cubes

Tags: three.js, mesh, raycasting, vertices

How do you combine a Square and a Rectangle into one object that a `Raycaster` can detect successfully?

I created a custom “Tree” object by making a “Trunk” - which is just a long rectangle, and then sticking a Square object on top of that Trunk.
I then “planted” that Tree on top of a Sphere, and I'm trying to get my `raycaster` to detect it.
It’s not working.

Here’s my code:

```
// My custom “Tree” Object:
var Tree = function(treeColor) {
    this.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
    this.mesh.name = "tree";

    // I start with the TRUNK - which is just an elongated Cube - meaning a Rectangle:
    var trunkGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(0.2, 0.5, 0.2);
    var trunkMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "blue", wireframe: false });
    var treeTrunk = new THREE.Mesh(trunkGeometry, trunkMaterial);
    treeTrunk.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    treeTrunk.rotation.x = -Math.PI * 0.5;
    this.mesh.add(treeTrunk);

    // Then I create the FOLIAGE - which is just a regular Cube:
    var foliageGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    var foliageMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: treeColor, wireframe: false });
    var treeFoliage = new THREE.Mesh(foliageGeometry, foliageMaterial);
    treeFoliage.position.set(0, 0.5, 0);

    // And then I attach/add the FOLIAGE to the TRUNK:
    treeTrunk.add(treeFoliage);
}



// Next I make a basic Sphere:
theSun = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 32, 24), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: "white", wireframe: false} ));
scene.add(theSun);


// And then I make a Tree and add it to my Sphere (`theSun`):
var oneTree = new Tree("red");
let rx = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
let ry = Math.random() * Math.PI;
oneTree.mesh.position.setFromSphericalCoords(3.2, ry, rx);
oneTree.mesh.lookAt(theSun.position);
theSun.add(oneTree.mesh);

// Next I add both theSun and the Tree to my “objectsForRayCasterArray” - a global var I use in my raycaster test:
objectsForRayCasterArray.push(oneTree);
objectsForRayCasterArray.push(theSun);


// In my render() function, I do the usual raycasting business:
        rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
        
    // Raycasting stuff:
    rayCaster.setFromCamera(mousePosition, camera);
     
    var intersectingObjectsArray = rayCaster.intersectObjects(objectsForRayCasterArray);
        
    if (intersectingObjectsArray.length > 0) {
        if (intersectedObject != intersectingObjectsArray[0].object) {
            console.log(“Intersected!”);
        }      
    }
```

NOTE: when I use this same code but instead of a `Tree` I just place a regular `Cube` on my `Sphere` object, everything works just fine. The `raycaster` detects the `Cube` and fires the `Alert`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that since you're nesting the `treeFoliage` inside `treeTrunk`, and that inside `mesh`, you're going to have to use a recursive intersection test.

According to the docs, [`intersectObjects()` accepts a second argument](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObjects) to perform a recursive hit-test. This means it will iterate through all descendants, instead of just doing a shallow check of top-level objects:

`rayCaster.intersectObjects(objectsForRayCasterArray, true);`

Comment: Hey you were right - sorta. The `Raycaster` DOES detect the Tree now - but not as a WHOLE. Meaning, when I mouse-over the Trunk, it - and only IT - lights up (I made it so the color changes to Yellow when anything is hovered over) but the FOLIAGE part stays normal. And when I mouse over the FOLIAGE, it turns Yellow - but the Trunk does not. So they're still treated as separate objects for some reason. Any further tips on correcting this?

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to vote if you found the answer helpful. And the behavior you're looking for is different. Simply doing `mesh.add(anotherMesh)` does not merge the geometries, it *nests* them. If you want to combine multiple cubes into a single object, consider using [`Geometry.merge`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Geometry.merge)

Comment: OK, `Geometry.mesh` - will definitely look into it!  Meanwhile, I marked yours as the right answer - thanks a million!